# How to sort integers in a sequence in Dafny?

Tags: sorting, sequence, dafny

As the title says, I wanna sort a sequence(rather than an array, which is easier). But I got a lot of problems(e.g. conversion between different datatypes, since sequences are immutable). And even bubble sort can't be proved for me. Any ideas?

Specifically, the goal is something as follow

```
method sort(a: seq<int>) returns (r: seq<int>)
  ensures |a| == |r|
  ensures multiset(a) == multiset(r)
  ensures forall i,j :: 0 <= i <= j < |r| ==> r[i] <= r[j]
{
  // implemetion here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a while to learn Dafny. You will need to learn the syntax and the semantics of the language. Verifying algorithms in Dafny is almost always coming down to induction of some property or other so start thinking about and practicing proofs by induction.

For this problem you should use sequence concatenation as well as sequence slices to break apart and recombine parts of the list. Generally, a recursive solution is fairly easy to construct for sequences in Dafny.

```
method sort(a: seq<int>) returns (r: seq<int>)
  ensures |a| == |r|
  ensures multiset(a) == multiset(r)
  ensures forall i,j :: 0 <= i <= j < |r| ==> r[i] <= r[j]
{
  if |a| <= 1 {
    return a;
  }else{
   var head := a[0];
   var tail := a[1..];
   assert a == a[0] + a[1..]; //Frequently you must include this for extensionality.
   //Do some sorting here.
  }
}
```

I recommend the book Program Proofs by Rustan Leino and his Dafny power user website. There are a couple of small blog posts about Dafny out there. I wrote a small series of blogs that are half tutorial and half problem explanation [here](https://dev.to/hath995/dafny-programming-language-and-software-verification-system-2afi).

I have verified a few examples of sorting [here](https://github.com/hath995/dafny/tree/main/FunctionalAlgorithms) and in the Program Proofs folder chapter 15.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really learned useful skills from your repository.